# How to get "the pump" without supplements or steroids?

Tags: muscle, blood-flow

I have never used any anabolic drugs/etc., but have used many, many supplements.

I am not able to successfully achieve "the pump" without supplements, however.

I use **very high doses** of nitric oxide stimulators, creatine, test boosters (not steroids -- mostly/all just placebo), high sugar (yes, simple sugars), high caffeine, and high protein/calories -- then start lifting and push as hard and long as possible. I get "the pump" like this, but without the previous mentioned stuff, I can't get a true pump. I know pumps are not really indicative of much, but I like knowing I can get the ***steroid pump*** without steroids/prohormones, but I'd like to get it without ANY supplements.

I have been training around 8 years and I'm very, very far from a beginner or even intermediate.

I have tried extremely high reps, low reps, medium reps, and low and high reps -- every combo, every angle, and cannot get " the pump" properly if I'm not taking supplements and etc.

I'm not asking for specific workout advice -- more so, just on how I can get the pump sans supps.

Comment: When you say "steriod pump". Do you mean anything order than a regular pump?

Comment: Are you confusing "pump" with "high blood pressure and heart rate"?

Comment: He's absolutely right, y'all.  Taking prohormones like Halodrol produces absolutely ridiculous back pumps (or so I've heard...) and they are attributed to a crazy amount of blood flowing through your body.  

That said, a proper pump is most definitely achievable without supplementation.  If anything, I'd remove caffeine from your 'stack' and really knock out high reps (like 50+) on your first warmup set while focusing on squeezing.  I'll frequently go after a chest pump before doing my sets of 315/405 on bench because I feel it "somehow" removes shoulder activation.  Pump is life.

Comment: Maybe try blood flow restriction training. BFR training produces really wicked pumps. It's not something I'd recommend for a beginner, but you have stated you're way beyond that. You can buy tourniquets designed specifically for BFR training which you wrap around your arms or legs. http://www.strongerbyscience.com/blood-flow-restriction-the-holy-grail-for-accessory-work/

Answer (score 1):

Sound like you are used to a stronger stimulus than the one normally archieved without supplements. Stop taking this stuff and after after a few weeks, when you are used to training without any pump, do carboloading the day before workout and try isometric exercise. Its a bit like you are used to drink a lot of coffee to wake up and now wondering why a cold shower alone is not enough anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Eat! Milk is a good example of a natural protein shake!
If you consume 1 gram of protein per pound of body weight, preferably consumed every three hours, you will grow, you don't need any supplements! There very profitable that's why they're marketed as though you need them! I have read that liquid protein must be consumed straight after a workout because it's absorbed quicker, but milk is slow releasing so it's not as good as whey protein, but that's from cheese anyway so I think it's just a marketing ploy!
Eat well and sleep well and you can build muscle without supplements!

Comment: You are right about good sleep and diet being essential for growth. But this was not the question asked. P.S. How come that you promote a scam product on your profile page? That does't really boost your credibility.